AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerMOSSE_create'
I´m trying to implement a CV2 tracker, following some examples and documentation, but I´ve encountered the following error:
self.tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'TrackerMOSSE_create
From my method:
import cv2
def create_tracker(self, tracker_type):
        if tracker_type == 'BOOSTING':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerBoosting_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'MIL':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerMIL_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'KCF':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerKCF_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'TLD':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerTLD_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'MEDIANFLOW':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerMedianFlow_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'GOTURN':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerGOTURN_create()
        elif tracker_type == 'MOSSE':
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerMOSSE_create()
        elif tracker_type == "CSRT":
            self.tracker = cv2.TrackerCSRT_create()

I´m using CV2 version 4.10.0 and  tried all tracker types, all reurning the same error.

For cv2 ver 4.10, the tracker class is now under the cv2.legacy so I updated my code to:
self.tracker = cv2.legacy.TrackerMOSSE_create()
